# Run-time error '1004' when adding validation to DataBodyRange

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I copy a cell validation from one workbook to another. An error occurs and I think it's due to the formula of the validation (because other validations are copied without problem), though I don't know why.

The validation formula is:

```
=OR(INDIRECT("tblRoutingLine[@OperationNoteMaster]")="";COUNTIF(INDIRECT("tblOperationNoteMaster[OperationNoteMasterID]");INDIRECT("tblRoutingLine[@OperationNoteMaster]"))=1)
```

My code (snippet) is:

```
Set valMasterColumnValidation = wbkMDRoutingRCGFileMaster.Worksheets(strTableWorksheet).ListObjects(1).ListColumns(colNewColumn.Name).DataBodyRange(1, 1).Validation
If intColumnValidationType <> 999 Then
    For j = 1 To colNewColumn.DataBodyRange.Cells.Count
        With colNewColumn.DataBodyRange(j, 1).Validation
            .Add Type:=valMasterColumnValidation.Type, _
                AlertStyle:=valMasterColumnValidation.AlertStyle, _
                Operator:=valMasterColumnValidation.Operator, _
                Formula1:=Replace(valMasterColumnValidation.Formula1, ";", ","), _
                Formula2:=Replace(valMasterColumnValidation.Formula2, ";", ",")
            .IgnoreBlank = valMasterColumnValidation.IgnoreBlank
            .InCellDropdown = valMasterColumnValidation.InCellDropdown
            .ErrorTitle = valMasterColumnValidation.ErrorTitle
            .ErrorMessage = valMasterColumnValidation.ErrorMessage
            .ShowError = valMasterColumnValidation.ShowError
        End With
    Next j
End If
```

Comment: Internally, Excel only works with english formulas and separators. I wonder why you are replacing `;` by `,` ! Though you see the formula with `;` it is stored otherwise. Try `Debug.print valMasterColumnValidation.Formula1` to see what's in there. Also check if the table and column names match to those in the target worksheet.

Comment: @WolfgangJacques: Thank you! The replace caused the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution (part of the code above):

```
Formula1:=valMasterColumnValidation.Formula1, _
Formula2:=valMasterColumnValidation.Formula2,
```